# QGIS - Save as GPX

Tags: qgis, gpx

I would like to convert .shp into .gpx. I tried to "save as" gpx but it gives an OGR error:

creation of field ObjectId failed (OGR error: Field of name 'Name' is not supported in GPX schema. Use GPX_USE_EXTENSIONS creation option to allow use of the  element.)

GPX_USE_EXTENSIONS=Y does not work.  Checking 'Skip Attribute Creation' does not work.

Answer (score 2):

In the **first** input box, insert: `GPX_USE_EXTENSIONS=YES`

and probably you want also `FORCE_GPX_TRACK=YES` in the **second** input box.

Comment: Still doesn't work. Pretends to, but the gpx cannot be imported into Mapsource/GPS.

Comment: Can you add it to QGIS with GPS Tools (Not using Add Vector Layer)? Can you open it with a text editor? Was target CRS set to EPSG:4326 WGS84?

Comment: I did not try to add it to QGIS (did not think of it, as that is not where I need it).  CRS layer was set to UTM, as that is what our GPS's are set for.

Comment: Tried adding to QGIS - does not work.  I converted it using DNR Garmin, but it would be nice if QGIS would do it.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: CRS of the layer must be set to WGS84 for GPX, regardless what you have set your GPS units display to. Thats the definition of GPX, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS_eXchange_Format

Comment: Ahh. Thank you. Is there a list somewhere of all the stuff that goes into the boxes?

Comment: No, every GDAL driver has its own page describing the supported parametres. For GPX, see http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_gpx.html